# Uyuni to San Pedro and not viceversa

Tags: chile, bolivia, salar-de-uyuni

I see most of posts are about tour guides from San Pedro de Acatama to Uyuni but I'm interested in the opposite direction.

I'm arriving in Uyuni, and going to San Pedro. I'm wondering which options do I have:

1. a tour of 3 days in the Salar De Uyuni, ending up in San Pedro. Then another tour from San Pedro to see all the sights around (such as the Moon Valley, etc..).
2. a longer tour from Uyuni, through the Salar De Uyuni, including the sights around San Pedro and finishing in San Pedro ? (How many days ?)

Are both options available? What are good tour operators, and how can I buy a package? Just walking around in Uyuni ?

Comment: *What are good tour operators* - can you define good?

Comment: @Karlson Ya sure! Popular/known by the community/with a good reputation.

Comment: That should probably go into your question. :)

Comment: @Karlson I believe it was clear, but now we have the comments supporting the question :)

Comment: If it was clear we wouldn't have to have this discussion in the comments, would we?  And generally speaking unless you make it clear questions become non-constructive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also started in Uyuni, on a standard three day tour you spend the first day on the salt lake, getting off it in the evening, then going further south the second day visiting various lakes and rock formations, the third day you are going back to Uyuni.

If you want to go to San Pedro you are dropped off at the border to Chile in the morning of the third day, from there you take a bus down to San Pedro. I don't think any of the Uyuni based 4x4s go into Chile.

If you take a four or five day tour from Uyuni, you may spend more time on the salt flats.

In San Pedro you have many options to take tours within Chile.

I don't know this for sure but I don't think there are operators that offer both Bolivia and Chile in one package.

In Uyuni there are tons of operators, I was happy with mine but don't remember the name. Shop around a little bit to get an idea of the prices. I didn't go with the cheapest one.

Comment: THanks, I'm arriving by flight in Uyuni in the afternoon, around 2 o'clock. So I don't think I will have a lot of time to go around (what time do the tourist offices close ?). Do you think I can buy a tour the day later, or do they start very early in the morning ?

Comment: I think we arrived in town around 4 or 5 (pm) and had enough time to shop around for a tour and find a place to stay. You should be fine. I would try to book the tour the day before and also find some people to go with. The tour operators may throw you in with a party of 5 which may not be fun if they stick together or don't speak your language(s). I was with a friend an Aussie guy and three Swiss girls, that was perfect.

Comment: Thanks, perfect. One more question, since I will ask them to leave me on the border with Chile, I will carry my backpack with me. Is it going to be an extra charge?Or just the same price ?

Comment: There was no extra charge for my bag, but I did buy the ticket for the bus between the border and San Pedro from the Uyuni operator, I think it was 8 or 10 USD In 2009. Other people on the tour who did the full circle back to Uyuni also took all their luggage with them on the tour.

Comment: Thing about this again, people may have left some luggage in Uyuni, but I did not pay extra for my bag